# importing css file as a raw file for webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have this as part of my webpack config

```
 {
    test: /\.css$/,
    oneOf: [
      {
        resourceQuery: /^\?raw$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        use: [
          // When using SSR, we use the mini css extract plugin so that we don't get FOUC in the
          // server rendered page. Also, the cache-loader does not work well with the plugin, so
          // only use the cache loader when not using SSR.
          ...(process.env.USE_SSR === 'true'
            ? [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader]
            : [
                {
                  loader: 'cache-loader',
                },
                'style-loader',
              ]),
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              minimize: true,
              localIdentName: '[folder]--[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:2]',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              config: {
                path: path.resolve(root, 'buildTools/webpack'),
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

and I imported a file like

```
@import '../../../@next/init/cloud/cloudChat.css?raw';
```

I am getting error on

Error: Failed to find '!!raw!../../../@next/init/cloud/cloudChat.css?raw'

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [`raw-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) in order to use raw.

If this is a one time import, you don't need to change webpack's config, and apply the loader inline.

```
import css from '!!raw-loader!../../../@next/init/cloud/cloudChat.css';
```

♥️ **Pay attention** to the double **!!**, they indicates to webpack to **not** apply regular (config based) loaders on this import.

Comment: its not a js import, its a css import